# Jquery selectable only with shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-selectable

I want to let the user select when the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is held.

```
$("#div").selectable({
        start: function(st) {
            $(window).keydown(function(e){
                if(!e.shiftKey){
                    st.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        });
```

no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten down your code to be much simpler by using the [`.shiftKey` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey) on the event directly (it's present in the `mousedown` event too), like this:

```
$("#div").mousedown(function(e){
   if(e.shiftKey) return;
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   return false;
}).selectable();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mRdLx/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(!e.shiftKey){
     $("#div").selectable({
        start: function(st) {
        st.stopPropagation();
          //your code here
        });

     }
});
```

if that doesn't work try use document instead of window or 'body'

Comment: the shift key is "shiftKey". what i'm asking is how to limit the user to only being able to select when the shift key is being held.

Answer (score 0):

for those who need it or something similar, this worked well for me:

```
    var shift = false;

    $(window).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.shiftKey){
    shift = true;
        }
    })
    .keyup(function(e){
        if(!e.shiftKey){
            shift = false;
        }
    });

    $("#div")
    .mousedown(function(e){
       if(!shift){
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         return false;          
       }
    })
    .selectable();
```